# Typescript type to save redux dispach action in useRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I am trying to save redux action `dispatch` in a React ref , via `useRef`, so I can use it to abort when clicked on a button. I am unable to give proper type to `useRef` hook.

```js
const buyerTypeRequest = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  buyerTypeRequest.current = dispatch(getBuyerType()); // Type 'Promise<PayloadAction<BuyerTypeResponse[], string, { arg: void; requestId: string; requestStatus: "fulfilled"; }, never>
}, [dispatch]);
```

Tried to find solution in the docs but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: You might find the `createAsynchThunk` [cancellation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#cancellation) docs helpful.

Answer (score 0):

why not write callback directly?

### without useCallback

```js
const buyerTypeRequest = () => dispatch(getBuyerType())
```

### with useCallback

```js
const buyerTypeRequest = useCallbac(() => dispatch(getBuyerType()), [dispatch, getBuyerType])
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, the use case is no longer valid, however I will try to use it for future use cases.